# Eclipse show me error The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int what's going wrong here and how to fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have no idea of how to fix this, i am just a beginner

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    int op;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("porfavor ingrese un numero entre 1 y 6: ");

    op=teclado.nextInt();

    if(op >=1 && <=6){

        System.out.println("muchas gracias");

    }else{

        System.out.println("error,el numero debe estar entre 1 y 6");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: This should be the line `if(op >=1 && op <=6){`

Answer (score 0):

Change `if(op >=1 && <=6)` to `if(op >=1 && op<=6)`

Comment: According to the title of the question, he's using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

`if(op >= 1 && op <= 6)`

`&&` is an infix operator that takes `boolean` and `boolean` and returns `boolean`. `<=` is an infix operator that takes `Number` and `Number` and returns `boolean`. Your expression is missing an argument.

Answer (score 0):

'&&' is a logical operator which works on boolean logic, here u are trying to use '&&'  on operator I.e. (op( >=1 && <=6)) which is not a defined usage in Java.. and most of the other languages
U just have to change it to (op >= 1 && op  <= 6)  in this way it is applied on two separate condition checks which will return boolean and '&&' can be applied on that